# Differences between these two implementations using the using-keyword

Tags: c#, using, unmanagedresources

Just for an example of creating a MD5 hash, microsoft provided this code sample:

### MSDN Code

```
// in Helpers class
public static string GetMd5Hash(MD5 md5Hash, string input)
{
    byte[] data = md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
    StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
    }
    return sBuilder.ToString();
}
```

and using it would be done like this

```
public string CreateHash(string str)
{
    using (var md5Hash = MD5.Create())
    {
        return Helpers.GetMd5Hash(md5Hash, str);
    }
}
```

### My Code

I thought changing the code Microsoft provided to this, would make it easier regarding reusability of the helper method:

```
// in Helpers class
public static string GetMd5Hash(string input)
{
    using (var md5Hash = MD5.Create())
    {
        byte[] data = md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder(); 
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
        }
        return sBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

So reusing it creates less code lines as a result:

```
public string CreateHash(string str)
{
    return Helpers.GetMd5Hash(str);
}
```

So what is the purpose of not doing it like I did in my second example? My initial thought was, that programmers, who use the code MSDN provided, would *always* be aware of the fact, that they use *unmanaged resources* (is this the right term?), whereas they wouldn't if they used my implementation.

Any other thoughts?

Comment: _Encrypt_ and _Hash_ are opposites.

Comment: did you just move the `using` statement from `CreateHash` to `GetMd5Hash` I don't see anything different in the code other than that? If thats the case then I don't see how its simpler?

Comment: @SLaks: I updated my post. I'm not an expert in this, so I don't know the terminoligy. This was just the first code in reach for creating this example.

Comment: @RedSerpent: Exaclty. I thought there is a reason, why Microsoft didn't chose to put the using into the body of `GetMd5Hash`.

Comment: And you really think there is any difference in these sets of codes?

Comment: I guess the MSDN code would be more efficient if you had to Encrypt multiple strings - it would only be created/disposed once and in your example it would be disposed of for each string?

Comment: @ssilas777: I do not know anything about *unmanaged resources*, so I thought there might be a difference.

Comment: Im not sure your explanation is correct, as anyone who will be using `Encrypy` is still going to be unaware of the underlying md5 object. There are different overloads of `Create`, so this might be a reason for creating the `MD5` outside the `Encrypt` method. also msdn is usually far from being perfect with its samples. Also, @SLaks, Encrypt and Hash are not opposites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s02tk69a.aspx) sample from msdn is abit more generic, as there are different overloads of `Create` on the `MD5` class, allowing to use different hashing algorithms.

Notice how they use it: whoever uses this function can provide any instance of the MD5 class, and it will work. Of course, as I said in my comment, their samples are usually far from being perfect and I dont think too much though's been put in it

Answer (score 2):

The MSDN code would be more efficient if you wanted to reuse the `md5Hash` in the scope of `CreateHash`